# How can I attach both Azure Data Lake Gen1 and Gen2 to a single Spark HD Insight cluster?

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-lake-gen2

I want to create an Azure HDI cluster that can access both ADLSg1 and ADLSg2 data lakes. Is this supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible for Spark 2.4 (HDI 4.0) with restrictions:

1. The cluster's primary storage **must** be Azure Blob
2. The cluster will authenticate with ADLSg1 and ADLSg2 through service principals + client secrets. The service principals and secrets must be managed manually.
3. This can't be done via the Azure Portal. You must change the cluster's `core-site.xml` configurations manually either via the Ambari UI or via ssh.

**Steps:**

1. [Find your Azure AD tenant ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-to-find-tenant)
2. [Register an application with Azure AD and create a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal) for each one of the ADLS accounts. Take note of the application ID(s).
3. [Create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret) for each one of the AAD applications created in step 1. Take note of the client secret(s) generated.
4. [Grant Owner role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-secure-data#assign-users-or-security-groups-to-data-lake-storage-gen1-accounts) to the service principal associated with the ADLSg1 account.
5. [Grant Storage Blob Data Owner role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json) to the service principal associated with the ADLSg2 account.
6. Deploy the HDI cluster with Azure Blob as primary storage only.
7. Open the [Ambari UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-manage-ambari) for the HDI cluster.
8. Navigate to HDFS → Configs tab UI → Advanced tab
9. Expand the "Custom core-site" section
10. Add the following settings:

For ADLS Gen 1:

```
fs.adl.oauth2.access.token.provider.type = ClientCredential
fs.adl.oauth2.client.id = <ADLSg1 Application ID>
fs.adl.oauth2.credential = <ADLSg1 Client Secret>
fs.adl.oauth2.refresh.url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant ID>/oauth2/token
```

For ADLS Gen 2:

```
fs.azure.account.auth.type.<ADLSg2 storage account name>.dfs.core.windows.net = OAuth
fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<ADLSg2 storage account name>.dfs.core.windows.net = org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<ADLSg2 storage account name>.dfs.core.windows.net = <ADLSg2 Application ID>
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<ADLSg2 storage account name>.dfs.core.windows.net = <ADLSg1 Client Secret>
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<ADLSg2 storage account name>.dfs.core.windows.net = https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant ID>/oauth2/token
```

11. Save the changes
12. Restart all affected services in the cluster (HDFS, YARN, etc.)

**To access files from the cluster:**

Use the fully qualified name. With this approach, you provide the full path to the file that you want to access.

- ADLSg1: `adl://<data_lake_account>.azuredatalakestore.net/<cluster_root_path>/<file_path>`
- ADLSg2: `abfs://<containername>@<accountname>.dfs.core.windows.net/<file.path>/`